# Excel VBA Select 2 not coherently cells and delete the rows

Tags: vba, excel

In a protected sheet i have a button that deletes the rows of the selected cells, while they are in coherently rows. If i select two cells in different rows (with CTRL), which are not in coherently rows i get a 1004 Error. See code below:

```
Sub LöscheDatensatz()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveSheet
    .unprotect Password:="test"
        If Cells(Selection.Row, 1).Locked = False Then
            Selection.EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    .Protect Password:="test", AllowFiltering:=True
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The if command prevents deleting protected rows. The error appear only in unprotected cells.

What is wrong in the code? Thank you =)

Comment: Is it possible that the selection is a "shape"?

Comment: How can a selection be a shape?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you protect a sheet, you need to explicitly allow rows deletion from users if you want to delete rows, even unlocked ones [1]. Check the correct box in you manually protect the sheet, or use code like following:

```
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="test", AllowFiltering:=True, AllowDeletingRows:=True
```

[1] btw, even with AllowDeletingRows to True, you won't be able to delete rows with protected cells.

Edit:

Test 1: new workbook, one sheet.

- Unlock rows 1 and 3 (select both rows, edit format cells, uncheck locked)
- Protect worksheet without allowing rows deletion
- Run in immediate windows [A1].EntireRow.Delete -> Error 1004 raised
- Run in immediate windows [A1,E3].EntireRow.Delete -> Error 1004 raised

Test 2: new workbook, one sheet.

- Unlock rows 1 and 3 (select both rows, edit format cells, uncheck locked)
- Protect worksheet with allowing rows deletion
- Run in immediate windows [A1,E3].EntireRow.Delete -> no error

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this doesn't work for me =/

I am talking only about the unprotected rows and cells.

|--> select one cell and run macro --> deleting the row of the selected cell
|--> select two cells among themselves e.g. row 1 and row 2 and run macro --> deleting the rows of the selected cells
|--> select two cells which are not following each other e.g. row 1 and row 3 and run macro --> error

Comment: My own tests shows that trying to delete an unlocked row without the AllowDeletingRows set to true on a protected sheet display the error too.

Comment: And a second test shows that deleting two separated unlocked rows on a sheet with AllowDeleteRows doesn't raise error.

Comment: Note that the whole rows need to be unlocked in order to be able to be deleted, if even only one cell on the row is still locked you will get an error.

Comment: Thank you, i can reproduce your answer in a blank sheet, which works, I'm trying now to transfer it to my worksheet.

Comment: Ok, my problem is, that i used the function "format as table". Before i format it, your answer works and i can delete separated, unblocked rows, but after formatting as table the code delivers an error.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is working fine.
Just make sure that all cells you are deleting are not locked.
Because as per your code. if you select non protected cell first and then protected cell. It will delete both the row, irrespective that second selected cell is protected(locked).

Below is the image for reference.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I get the error in unprotected cells. E.g., i select one unprotected cell in a unprotected row e.g. A4 and the same e.g. E10, which is also a unprotected cell in a unprotected row, run the macro and get the error 1004.